# Recursive CTE trouble

Tags: sql-server, common-table-expression

I'm having some trouble coming up with the CTE way of doing a task. I already have a loop method and it is fast enough, but I wanted to do it in a proper way to better learn and understand CTE usage.

SQL:

```
DECLARE @Income MONEY=125000.00,
    @Active INT=0,
    @Year CHAR(4)='2018'

DECLARE @T TABLE ([Year] CHAR(4),Active INT,UpperLimit MONEY,Factor DECIMAL(6,3))
INSERT INTO @T ([Year],Active,UpperLimit,Factor) SELECT '2018',0,5000.0,1.00;
INSERT INTO @T ([Year],Active,UpperLimit,Factor) SELECT '2018',0,100000.0,0.85;
INSERT INTO @T ([Year],Active,UpperLimit,Factor) SELECT '2018',0,500000.0,0.80;
INSERT INTO @T ([Year],Active,UpperLimit,Factor) SELECT '2018',0,999999999.0,0.75;

WITH GradientCTE ([Year], Active, UpperLimit, Factor,[Income],WeightedValue,[Row])  
AS  
(  
    SELECT [Year], Active, UpperLimit, Factor
        ,@Income AS [Income]
        ,CAST(0.0 AS DECIMAL(16,3))AS WeightedValue
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [Year],Active ORDER BY UpperLimit ASC) AS [Row]
    From  @T
)
SELECT *
FROM GradientCTE
ORDER BY UpperLimit
```

TLDR version; current output:

```
Year    Active  UpperLimit     Factor   Income      WeightedValue   Row
2018    0       5000.000       1.000    125000.000  0.000           1
2018    0       100000.000     0.850    125000.000  0.000           2
2018    0       500000.000     0.800    125000.000  0.000           3
2018    0       999999999.000  0.750    125000.000  0.000           4
```

What I would like:

```
Year    Active  UpperLimit    Factor    Income      WeightedValue   Row
2018    0       5000.000       1.000    125000.000  5000.000        1
2018    0       100000.000     0.850    120000.000  85000.000       2
2018    0       500000.000     0.800     20000.000  16000.000       3
2018    0       999999999.000  0.750         0.000  0.000           4
```

**Explained**:

Currently, the looping logic goes over the set row by row and reduces @Income by the UpperLimit for each row until no money is left. It uses that to multiply that amount by the Factor to get a weighted amount. So, in the example provided, the starting income is 125,000.00. The first 5000 are at full weight (1.00), so we reduce the income by 5000 and move the the next row saving the summed weighted value. This is done until income is 0. So, 125,000 should come out to (5000 * 1.0) + (100000 * 0.85) + (20000 * 0.80) + (0.00 * 0.75) or 106,000 total if summed.

Comment: Would you mind adding the result you'd like to see?

Comment: 125,000 should come out to (5000 * 1.0) + (100000 * 0.85) + (20000 * 0.80) + (0.00 * 0.75) In the first 2 rows you are using the (upperlimit * Factor )where as in the last 2 rows you are using (Income * Factor) to compute weighted value .Please explain.

Comment: @rmehra76 The UpperLimit is a cap on how much of my income can be applied to that row. So, 5000 is all that is allowable in row one; with the 5000 removed, that leaves us 120,000 for row two. Row two only allows 100,000 to be used which leaves us 20,000. 20,000 does not exceed row three's upper limit so the 20,000 is applied to that row's factor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Ross Bush's answer, it led me down the right track to solve the problem. From a maintenance standpoint, I think a looping pattern is easier to understand, so I likely won't implement the CTE version and performance isn't an issue as the data set is tiny.

```
DECLARE @Income DECIMAL(18,3)=125000.00,
    @Active INT=0,
    @Year CHAR(4)='2018'

DECLARE @T TABLE ([Year] CHAR(4),Active INT,UpperLimit DECIMAL(18,3),Factor DECIMAL(18,3))
INSERT INTO @T ([Year],Active,UpperLimit,Factor) SELECT '2018',0,5000.0,1.00;
INSERT INTO @T ([Year],Active,UpperLimit,Factor) SELECT '2018',0,100000.0,0.85;
INSERT INTO @T ([Year],Active,UpperLimit,Factor) SELECT '2018',0,500000.0,0.80;
INSERT INTO @T ([Year],Active,UpperLimit,Factor) SELECT '2018',0,999999999.0,0.75;
;WITH GradientCTE 
AS  
(  
    SELECT DISTINCT
        [YEAR],Active,UpperLimit=0.00, Factor = 0.00, [Row] = 0
    FROM @T
    UNION ALL
    SELECT [Year],Active,UpperLimit, Factor
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [Year],Active ORDER BY UpperLimit ASC) AS [Row]
    From  @T
)
,Reduce AS (
    SELECT 
        [YEAR],Active,CAST(@Income AS DECIMAL(18,3)) AS [RemainingIncome], 
        Row, 
        Factor
        ,UpperLimit
        ,CAST(0.00 AS DECIMAL(18,3)) AS WeightedValue
    FROM GradientCTE
    WHERE UpperLimit=0
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        g.[YEAR],g.Active,CASE WHEN CAST([RemainingIncome] - G.UpperLimit AS DECIMAL(18,3)) < 0 THEN 0 ELSE CAST([RemainingIncome] - G.UpperLimit AS DECIMAL(18,3))  END AS [RemainingIncome], 
        G.Row,
        g.Factor
        ,g.UpperLimit
        ,CAST(CASE WHEN [RemainingIncome]>G.UpperLimit  THEN G.UpperLimit * G.Factor ELSE R.[RemainingIncome] * G.Factor END AS DECIMAL(18,3)) AS WeightedValue
    FROM GradientCTE G
    INNER JOIN Reduce R ON R.Row = G.Row -1
       AND g.Year=r.Year
       AND g.Active=r.Active
)
SELECT
    *
    -- [Year],Active,SUM(WeightedValue)
FROM Reduce
WHERE [RemainingIncome] >= 0
--GROUP BY [Year],Active
```

Answer (score 1):

You can reduce the results within another CTE, recursively. I added a UNION with 0 to in the first set to produce the first line showing the starting income.

```
DECLARE @Income DECIMAL(18,3)=125000.00,
    @Active INT=0,
    @Year CHAR(4)='2018'

DECLARE @T TABLE ([Year] CHAR(4),Active INT,UpperLimit DECIMAL(18,3),Factor DECIMAL(18,3))
INSERT INTO @T ([Year],Active,UpperLimit,Factor) SELECT '2018',0,5000.0,1.00;
INSERT INTO @T ([Year],Active,UpperLimit,Factor) SELECT '2018',0,100000.0,0.85;
INSERT INTO @T ([Year],Active,UpperLimit,Factor) SELECT '2018',0,500000.0,0.80;
INSERT INTO @T ([Year],Active,UpperLimit,Factor) SELECT '2018',0,999999999.0,0.75;
;WITH GradientCTE 
AS  
(  
    SELECT ReduceAmount = 0, UpperLimit=0.00, Factor = 0.00, Row = 0
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ReduceAmount = UpperLimit * Factor, UpperLimit, Factor
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [Year],Active ORDER BY UpperLimit ASC) AS [Row]
    From  @T
)
,Reduce AS (
    SELECT 
        Income = CAST(@Income AS DECIMAL(18,3)), 
        Row, 
        ReduceAmount
    FROM GradientCTE
    WHERE ReduceAmount=0
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        Income = CASE WHEN CAST(Income - G.ReduceAmount AS DECIMAL(18,3)) < 0 THEN 0 ELSE CAST(Income - G.ReduceAmount AS DECIMAL(18,3))  END, 
        G.Row,
        G.ReduceAmount
    FROM GradientCTE G
    INNER JOIN Reduce R ON R.Row = G.Row -1
)

SELECT  * FROM Reduce
WHERE
    Income >= 0
```

Comment: This did not solve my problem, but led me down the right path. Many thanks!

Comment: Yea, after I compared results to the desired results you updated I realized mine were off. I would be interested in the solution, if you want to post it.

Answer (score 1):

```
         DECLARE @Income MONEY=125000.00,
         @Active INT=0,
         @Year CHAR(4)='2018',
         @vIncome Money = 0

        DECLARE @T TABLE ([Year] CHAR(4),Active INT,UpperLimit MONEY,Factor 
        DECIMAL(6,3))
        INSERT INTO @T ([Year],Active,UpperLimit,Factor) SELECT 
         '2018',0,5000.0,1.00;
          INSERT INTO @T ([Year],Active,UpperLimit,Factor) SELECT 
   '2018',0,100000.0,0.85;
   INSERT INTO @T ([Year],Active,UpperLimit,Factor) SELECT 
  '2018',0,500000.0,0.80;
   INSERT INTO @T ([Year],Active,UpperLimit,Factor) SELECT 
  '2018',0,999999999.0,0.75;




   Select * ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [Year],Active ORDER BY 
   UpperLimit ASC) AS [Row],CAST(0.0 AS DECIMAL(16,3))AS Income,CAST(0.0 AS 
   DECIMAL(16,3))AS WeightedValue
   into #tmp from @T t1



    --Select (t2.UpperLimit * t2.Factor),t2.*,t1.Row as prev,t1.UpperLimit 
 --from #tmp t1
  --inner join #tmp t2 on (t1.Row = t2.Row +1)  

   update t2
   set 
   @vIncome = @Income,
    @Income = case when (@Income > t2.UpperLimit) then  
                @Income - t2.UpperLimit 
          else 
                0 
          end,
  t2.Income = @Income,
  t2.WeightedValue = case when (@vIncome > t2.UpperLimit) then 
                            (t2.UpperLimit * t2.Factor) 
                    else

                        @vIncome *t2.Factor
                    end

   from #tmp t1
   inner join #tmp t2 on (t1.Row = t2.Row +1)

  Select * from #tmp  


  drop table #tmp
```

Comment: Tried to achieve the same output without recursive CTE .Used a self join,temp table  and update statement.@UnhandledExcepSean , Let me know your feedback on this

Comment: Thanks for your input; I appreciate the time you spent, but it is not producing the expected results and not a CTE. The CTE was the biggest desire as I already had a solution using temp storage and looping. It looks like your solution is missing the 85,000 data. I have a solution in my answer above if you'd like to see.

Comment: Yes , you are right I was doing a wrong comparision.Thank you.         btw ,I have updated my solution.